# Facebook Graph empty data for likes, tags etc

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

1) I'm wondering why the Facebook Graph gives empty results for the following objects:

(Please keep in mind I have a token that has the correct permissions, moreover, extended permissions to access these objects).

- tagged - https://graph.facebook.com/me/tagged or /{userid}/tagged
- likes
- activities
- accounts

which produces:
{"data": []}

2) Did Facebook strip our permissions from accessing our own data?

3) Which objects cannot be accessed?

4) Here are my extended /permissions

```
<pre>
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "status_update": 1, 
      "publish_checkins": 1, 
      "photo_upload": 1, 
      "video_upload": 1, 
      "sms": 1, 
      "email": 1, 
      "create_event": 1, 
      "create_note": 1, 
      "export_stream": 1, 
      "share_item": 1, 
      "rsvp_event": 1, 
      "read_stream": 1, 
      "publish_stream": 1, 
      "read_mailbox": 1, 
      "ads_management": 1, 
      "read_friendlists": 1, 
      "manage_friendlists": 1, 
      "xmpp_login": 1, 
      "read_insights": 1, 
      "read_requests": 1, 
      "manage_notifications": 1, 
      "manage_pages": 1, 
      "publish_actions": 1, 
      "user_birthday": 1, 
      "user_religion_politics": 1, 
      "user_relationships": 1, 
      "user_relationship_details": 1, 
      "user_hometown": 1, 
      "user_location": 1, 
      "user_likes": 1, 
      "user_activities": 1, 
      "user_interests": 1, 
      "user_education_history": 1, 
      "user_work_history": 1, 
      "user_online_presence": 1, 
      "user_website": 1, 
      "user_groups": 1, 
      "user_events": 1, 
      "user_photos": 1, 
      "user_videos": 1, 
      "user_photo_video_tags": 1, 
      "user_notes": 1, 
      "user_checkins": 1, 
      "user_questions": 1, 
      "user_about_me": 1, 
      "user_status": 1, 
      "user_games_activity": 1, 
      "user_subscriptions": 1, 
      "friends_birthday": 1, 
      "friends_religion_politics": 1, 
      "friends_relationships": 1, 
      "friends_relationship_details": 1, 
      "friends_hometown": 1, 
      "friends_location": 1, 
      "friends_likes": 1, 
      "friends_activities": 1, 
      "friends_interests": 1, 
      "friends_education_history": 1, 
      "friends_work_history": 1, 
      "friends_online_presence": 1, 
      "friends_website": 1, 
      "friends_groups": 1, 
      "friends_events": 1, 
      "friends_photos": 1, 
      "friends_videos": 1, 
      "friends_photo_video_tags": 1, 
      "friends_notes": 1, 
      "friends_checkins": 1, 
      "friends_questions": 1, 
      "friends_about_me": 1, 
      "friends_status": 1, 
      "friends_games_activity": 1, 
      "friends_subscriptions": 1
    }
  ]
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked them, I don't see any tags (but not sure if I have been tagged in the last few days).

The other ones work perfectly for me when tested in the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. So are you sure your account has likes/activities and more then one account? Since I only see my 'pages' of which I am also owner.